# Can I make a summary of only selected data?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to select only certain rows and columns and use the same "summary of responses" feature but for limited data rather than all of it. Is this possible?

The report is with ALL DATA from this sheet - I want the exact same output but with only certain email addresses.

Google Form: bit.ly/bilvalchal_results

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us and show us the expected outcome?

Comment: Jacob - I did share the doc:) bit.ly/bilvalchal_results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a google spreadsheet can I make a summary of only selected data?

Yes, but I think your Title may be misleading. I thought at first you wanted any summary but now believe you want the specific format provided by Form > Show summary of responses, and that is quite different.

> Is this possible?

In essence, I think not. For example, in Excel it is easy enough to avoid charting data simply by hiding it. That seems not to work here. Even deleting data in the Form responses sheet does not change the Summary of responses.

This presumably because both the Form responses sheet and the Summary of responses are distinct views of server-side data. I doubt there is a means for a user to control the code that drives the Summary of responses, whose data is gathered from the individual form submissions (as is the data shown in the responses sheet). Submissions have spawned both the sheet and the Summary but the two are independent of one another.

> On the other hand.

As mentioned by @zeroCoder, equivalent results might be obtained by a user though it would seem with a considerable effort. A script may be required to set the chart type to use for each question by question type (if to avoid an ad-hoc basis, Form by Form). Once the type appropriate to each column has been determined it would be a little tedious but not difficult to create the corresponding chart. Adjusting the formatting, scales etc to match that of Summary of responses would also be tedious but with a script would not need to be purpose-built for each Form individually.

That said, I hope I am crassly mistaken and that actually it is quite easy. I suspect however you would have heard by now were that so.

Comment: > Even deleting data in the Form responses sheet does not change the Summary of responses.
> This presumably because both the Form responses sheet and the Summary of responses are distinct views of server-side data. (…)

have you checked this lately, with **new** Sheets? (i.e. URL not starting with `docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?…`  but `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…` or `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/edit?…`)

just asking because I found some posts in google product forums [1][2] telling that the old behaviour has changed. I haven’t checked it though.

(will put links in a new comment)

Comment: [1] https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/eku9nBAvFVA/WuZ-PaLPeqcJ
[2] https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/OoVpUZyesrA/pbrGON8Cv-8J

Comment: thank you for your feedback - I am not sure how I could have made it clearer in the TITLE ALONE but I love these exchanges not just for the answers I seek but for the exercise in clarifying ones self (seriously:). Happy New Year @pnuts

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [Awesome Tables](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/awesome-tables/dashboard-for-google-form) web app. It allows filtering of your data (and more). It is available as a gadget on Google Sites.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pivot tables here are some tutorials on how to use them:

- [How to create a pivot table report](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en)
- [Summarize your data with pivot tables](https://drive.googleblog.com/2011/05/summarize-your-data-with-pivot-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn't use the built in feature exactly but it does the trick.

Take your sheet with all the rows and figure out which columns you want to show.

Create a new sheet called preview or whatever.

in the top cell for each column reference the row from the responses sheet like this `={'Form Responses 1'!A:A}`

Then hit `File`>`Publish to web` and chose to publish your Preview sheet only.

Get your shared link (shorten it if you must).

Post that url in your form only and presto.

You win!